# Повторять цикл, пока ввод неверен

Tags: javascript

> Напишите цикл, который предлагает prompt ввести число, большее 100. Если посетитель ввёл другое число – попросить ввести ещё раз, и так далее.
>
> Цикл должен спрашивать число пока либо посетитель не введёт число, большее 100, либо не нажмёт кнопку Cancel (ESC).

У меня не работает почему?

```js
var a = prompt('Введите число больше 100', '');
while(true){
    if(a > 100 || a == null) break
}
```

Comment: Если ввели "1e4" - это считается больше 100? ;-)

Comment: @xes `parseInt(a)` - если нужно чтобы числа вроде 1e4 не засчитывались

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно каждый раз вызывать prompt :)

```js
while(true){
    var a = prompt('Введите число больше 100', '');
    if(a > 100 || a == null) break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 
</head>
<body>
<p>Напишите цикл, который предлагает            prompt ввести число, большее 100. Если           посетитель ввёл другое число – попросит           ь ввести ещё раз, и так
 далее.</p>
<script>
var userName;
while(true){
userName=prompt("скоко вам лет","");
if(userName>100){
 break;
  }
  alert("нет другое");
} 
alert("да");
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не понятно, чем код принципиально отличается от принятого ответа... Тем, что сообщает про неверный ввод? Это можно переписать в виде одного prompt вне цикла, а внутри цикла уже позапускать prompt с другим текстом. Тогда человеку не придется лишний раз тыкать на "ok"